# Load image via URL into RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an API which returns JSON and I would like to load an Image from a URL which is provided by this API. The Image should be passed into Adapter for a Recycling View. 
Right now all Items which contain an Imgae_URL are getting skipped by my Adapter and I dont really understand why.

```
if (json_img_url.isNotEmpty()) {
  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute({
    val conn = URL(json_img_url).openConnection()
    conn.connect()
    val iStream:InputStream = conn.getInputStream()
    val img_bitmap:Bitmap? = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream)
    newItems.add(Item(....img_bitmap))
})
....
itemArrayAdapter.addItems(newItems)
```

URL :`"https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/c...."`
The URls used are valid and Images on the S3 Bucket are all public.

The If statment returns `true` (I checked with `Log.d`) but the Item does not appear on the Phone, I dont recive an error and the app does not crash its just like the Item was never there...

I know there are librarys like Picasso or Glide but even with them I could not make it work and to be honest I would like to accomplish this task without a having to install an extra package, it just feels wrong.

Comment: you can use image loader library like glide in your adapter to load image,
provide full image url to help you better.

Comment: did you notify RecyclerView that the item was inserted?

Comment: Yes I think issue is that adapter is not notified after adding items!!

Comment: Thanks to Stefan and Rushabh for the suggestions, the problem came from the emulator I used, on a normal phone everything works fine. Seemed to be a problem with the storage....

Comment: Welcome to SO hansTheFranz, please consider updating your answer with the actual reason this was not working or closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike ListView, there is no way to add or remove items directly through the RecyclerView adapter. You need to make changes to the data source directly and notify the adapter of any changes.There are many method available to use when notifying the adapter of different changes:

- notifyItemChanged(int pos) : Notify that item at position has changed.
- notifyItemInserted(int pos): Notify that item reflected at position has been newly inserted.
- notifyItemRemoved(int pos): Notify that items previously located at position has been removed from the data set.
- notifyDataSetChanged(): Notify that the dataset has changed. Use only as last resort.

Every time we want to add or remove items from the RecyclerView, we will need to explicitly inform to the adapter of the event. Unlike the ListView adapter, a RecyclerView adapter should not rely on notifyDataSetChanged() since the more granular actions should be used. See the [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) for more details.

Also, if you are intending to update an existing list, make sure to get the current count of items before making any changes. For instance, a `getItemCount()` on the adapter should be called to record the first index that will be changed.

```
// record this value before making any changes to the existing list
int curSize = itemArrayAdapter.getItemCount();

// update the existing list
newItems.add(Item(....img_bitmap));

// curSize should represent the first element that got added
// newItems.size() represents the itemCount
itemArrayAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(curSize, newItems.size());
```

Comment: Unfortunately updating the Adapter was not the Problem, It was a Emulator/filestorage problem. Thanks for the detailed answer, I definitly learned something.